# SQL: Error when converting varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

```
WITH Valid_dates (ValidDate)
AS
(
    SELECT '19' + SUBSTRING(column, 0, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(column, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(column, 5, 2) AS ValidDate
    FROM table
    WHERE SUBSTRING(column, 3, 2) <= '12' --Max month
    AND SUBSTRING(column, 3, 2) >= '01' --Min month
    AND ISNULL(SUBSTRING(column, 3, 2), '') <> '' --Empty string
    AND SUBSTRING(column, 5, 2) <= '31' --Max day
    AND SUBSTRING(column, 5, 2) >= '01' --Min month
    AND ISNULL(SUBSTRING(column, 5, 2), '') <> '' --Empty string
    AND LEN('19' + SUBSTRING(column, 0, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(column, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(column, 5, 2)) = 10 --Must match 10 character format
)

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, ValidDate)
FROM Valid_dates
```

When I execute this query in SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following error message: "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

I have filtered out all invalid dates. Non-existent dates such as Feb 30, Apr 31, Jun 31 etc. are not filtered out per se as you can see, but I have checked for them, and they do not exist. Running only the CTE query yields plenty of results with which I can not find any discrepancies.

Comment: does it work or fail on any small subset of data, e.g just try your SQL on some single records - if it always fails you are feeding it wrong data, if it sometimes fails then you probably have some invalid date in there like 29/02/1900 for example

Comment: what if you do a SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, ValidDate) order by validdtae, and if it fails try SELECT TOP 1  ValidDate order by validdtae - what is going into there?

Comment: What is the input (the acutal content) of your *column* in *table*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with SQL Server.  It does not guarantee the *order of evaluation* of clauses in the query.  There is no sense that the `where` (even in the CTE) is evaluated "before" the rest of the query.

Note:  This is a *feature* of the optimizer.  By rearranging the evaluation of different components of the query, the optimizer can create a better query plan.

In SQL Server 2012+, the simplest method is `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
with . . .
select try_convert(datetime, validdate)
from valid_dates;
```

In earlier versions, you can use `case`:

```
select (case when <all your conditions here>
             then convert(datetime, validdate)
        end)
```

SQL Server *does* guarantee the sequential evaluation of `case` statements under normal circumstances (there are some quirky situations with aggregations), so this also fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm not convinced, are you saying that unselected data has to legally convert in the selected field list?  I understood that the generation of the final list of selected fields was the last step, so for example eliminating Divisor of zero in 'WHERE' would stop division by zero error

Comment: @AndrewDeighton . . . It doesn't matter if you are convinced or not.  This is how SQL Server works.  The SQL optimizer reserves the right to rearrange processing, and this might introduce errors into processing.  This is a known problem, it has been around for a long time, and is presumably related to why `try_convert()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: he only needs one invalid date in there and it won't work, I would advise him to pursue other avenues first, such as what happens if he checks that day is less than 29 for example - would that still give an error?  Maybe you have his data set to check all this though, otherwise your answer is pretty much a guess - as is mine, that's why I'm telling him to try some stuff out.  If he queries his selected data into a temp table, would it then all convert?  According to your theory, it should do.  So yeah I think it's a bad answer!

Comment: So the select clause might get evaluated before the where clause, but it will always get executed after it?

Comment: you could experiment in this case by select the CTE into #temp, then running the select on #temp separately - that would show that it was an issue with the order of operations being carried out, otherwise if it failed it would suggest a data error

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer I think this has nothing to do with CTE, but is culture related...

Comment: @shnugo - that's a very good point, could he then remove the dashes, therefore creating an iso format, e.g. '19921231', said to be immune to date formatting errors by some

Comment: @AndrewDeighton, read my answer, especially the *UPDATE*, this might be much easier...

Comment: @Shnugo . . . Although the culture could be a problem, SQL Server is well known for moving calculations into the table scan operator *before* filtering the data.  Occam's Razor suggests that is the primary cause of the error.

Comment: We've no idea whether invalid dates are getting through the filter or not, it is certainly capable of letting invalid dates through it seems to me, so it's a matter of speculation as to whether or not Occam's Razor tells us anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is culture related.

You did not specify the actual input, from your code I suppose it is some unseparated format without a year like 920130 meaning the 30th of January in 1992?

This will be transformed in something like `1992-01-30`.

Your default culture is probably one using something like `yyyy-dd-mm` which will lead into out-of-range error with a "month" higher than 12...

Try to use 102 as culture key:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, ValidDate,102)
FROM Valid_dates
```

### UPDATE

If my assumptions are true, it was much easier to try

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('19' + column AS DATE) FROM table
```

SQL Server allows natively to cast unseparated strings looking like `yyyymmdd`. Using `TRY_CAST` will return `NULL` if the cast is not possible.

With older versions (<2012) use this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE('19' + column)=1 THEN CAST('19' + column AS DATE) ELSE NULL END FROM table
```