# Concatenating Time and DateTime in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to combine a `SmallDateTime` field and a `Time` value (result of a scalar-valued function) into a `DateTime` and I keep getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

---

Here are the variables used throughout:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATETIME AS DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATETIME AS DATETIME
SELECT @STARTDATETIME = '8/29/2016 12:00:00'
SELECT @ENDDATETIME = '8/30/2016 12:00:00'
```

Column definitions:

```
FT_START_DATE   SmallDateTime
FT_END_DATE     SmallDateTime
FT_START_TIME   Int
FT_END_TIME     Int
```

The date fields do not contain timestamps. The time fields are basically 24 hour time without the colon dividers. (Example: 142350 = 14:23:50)

Here's the function that is called in my queries:

```
USE [PWIN171]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[dbo.IPC_Convert_Time]    Script Date: 9/13/2016 4:50:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[dbo.IPC_Convert_Time] 
(
    @time int
)
RETURNS time
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result time
    SELECT @Result = CONVERT(time
                            , STUFF(
                                STUFF(
                                    RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), @time), 6) 
                                , 5, 0, ':')
                            , 3, 0, ':')
                        )
    RETURN @Result
END
```

---

Example 1 - Fails:

This is what I'm after in general.

```
SELECT * FROM FT WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
CAST(FT_END_DATE AS DATETIME) + DBO.[dbo.IPC_Convert_Time](FT_END_TIME) BETWEEN @STARTDATETIME AND @ENDDATETIME;
```

Example 2 - Works:

This one runs, but it won't get records from 8/29 because the end dates will be before 12:00:00 on 8/29.

```
SELECT * FROM FT WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
FT_END_DATE BETWEEN @STARTDATETIME AND @ENDDATETIME
AND CAST(FT_END_DATE AS DATETIME) + DBO.[dbo.IPC_Convert_Time](FT_END_TIME) BETWEEN @STARTDATETIME AND @ENDDATETIME;
```

I suppose I could do one where I split apart my paramters and check that the end time is between the time portion of the parameters as well, but that seems to be a step in the wrong direction. The error seems to only appear when there is no other usage of `FT_START_DATE` or `FT_END_DATE` in the where clause.

The time converting function works fine in every scenario I have created. I have even tried Example 2 with parameters that would give it 100% overlap with the data covered by Example 1 in case there was bad data causing the error, but it runs fine.

I also don't know exactly where the error is occurring, because it only references the line the select statement begins on, and not the actual location in the code.

Why does it behave like this?

### UPDATE:

TIMEFROMPARTS is not available because this is on SQL Server 2008

Comment: There is no month 29. If you have to use date literals use either the unseparated date format `20160829` or the full ISO 8601 format. Furthermore, whatever `IPC_Convert_Time` does, you don't need string manipulation to create a `time` value. There are probably many other bugs, eg why cast `FT_END_DATE` if it's already a date type? Why use `smalldatetime` instead of `date` or `datetime` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The fields are set by the vendor and can't be changed. I cast to `datetime` because if I don't, the end result of the `+` operation will also be `smalldatetime`, and therefore will round off the seconds. Why don't I need string manipulation to create a time value from the int columns?

Comment: The main point is that you are using US-specific strings for dates, which is guaranteed to fail anywhere outside the US. Since you don't mention *where* the error occurs, that's the first thing that may fail. String manipulation exposes you to more such problems. Use [TIMEFROMPARTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx) to create a `time` value since you already have each part

Comment: The scope of this question is within one database, within one US based company, within one time zone. While the system is not well designed, it is impeccable in it's consistency.

Comment: And yet, it fails. Without knowing *where*, it's either that literal or the function. Why don't you replace the function with `TIMEFROMPARTS` and eliminate strings?

Comment: PS `NOLOCK` doesn't mean "don't take locks", it means "don't wait for other transactions to finish and read even dirty data". This suggests locking issues. Perhaps you should use `READPAST` to ignore locked rows, or snapshot isolation

Comment: It fails, but it also works just fine over the exact same data with a change in the where clause. I will work up a version using TIMEFROMPARTS, but I will still need to manipulate my time fields because they are not directly compatible with that function.

Comment: @Logarr Please check my update

Comment: Might be related with this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38741536/5089204

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, this can be done much simpler:

Try this:

```
DECLARE @d DATE=GETDATE();
DECLARE @t TIME=GETDATE();
SELECT @d;
SELECT @t;
SELECT CAST(@d AS datetime)+CAST(@t AS datetime);
```

A *pure* date and a *pure* time can simply be added to combine them...

### UPDATE Read your question again...

Try this

```
SELECT FT_END_DATE
      ,FT_END_TIME 
      ,CAST(FT_END_DATE AS DATETIME) + DBO.[dbo.IPC_Convert_Time](FT_END_TIME) AS CombinedTime
      ,* 
FROM FT
```

to see if your attempt is doing the right thing.

If yes, it might help to create a CTE and do the filter on the named column.

Sometimes the engine **does not work the order you would expect this**.

As CTEs are fully inlined it is quite possible, that this will not help...

SQL Server is well knwon for bringing up such errors, because a type check happens **before** a conversion took place...

It might be an idea to use the given SELECT with `INTO #tbl` to push the result set into a new table and do your logic from there...

Comment: There's the `SELECT @STARTDATETIME = '8/29/2016 12:00:00'` line too, which could be just one of the lines that can throw a conversion error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, true... One should never use culture specific date literals...

Comment: The `IPC_Convert_Time` function probably should be replaced with the built-in TIMEFROMPARTS function too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, well, AFAIU the OP has got a time like '174112' which has to be converted to '17:41:12'. It seems to be valid to do this on string base with `STUFF`...

Comment: Thanks for the update. The query does run fine. I did a thorough test where I grabbed the data this query should find, placed it into a table with matching types, and then ran the function on all the records. It passed. Which tells me the problem is not in the function, but has something to do with how the where clause gets interpreted.

Comment: @Logarr as written below your question: SQL Server sometimes checks the datatypes **before** you converted them... Try to copy your data **with the combined column** in a new table and check if your query delivers correctly from there...